# Exception Handling without using 'Catch' keyword

Tags: php, exception

I want to create a class in my framework for exception handling.
How can write the class to be able doing exception handling without using try catch in my codes?
Here is a example:

I tried but couldn't write the code here

```
exception.php  

class Soroush_Exception extends   
    //some code here      
} 

===============================  
file1.php  

$a = 2;  
if ($a != 3)  
{  
    throw new Soroush_Exception("Error");   
}  
//and here I want to show it without using catch with a static method  
echo Soroush_Exception::show();
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Your link doesn't work (500 error). And maybe explain why you want this. It sounds like a bad idea :(

Comment: Your post may have been blocked because you did not apply code formatting, [see here for how it's done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Why would you want to emulate exception handling without try/catch? That's essentially the whole point of exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger_error function: php.net/trigger_error

Answer (score 0):

Set a class' method as [exception handler](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) - it will catch any exception, that was not catched explicitly with a `catch` statement.

The problem is that exception stops execution of the script to the point where it is catched, and continue from the catch afterwards. If there is no catch, you still can execute code in the exception handler, but after the handler method the script will stop.